# Inverse of function with two Exponential Eulers Terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

How can I go about getting the inverse of$ f(t) = e^{-.001t}\cdot e^{-.005t}$?
I have found a couple of calculators online that suggest that the answer is:
$t=-166.667\ln(y)$, but I would like to know the steps. I know how to solve this for a single Euler term.

Comment: **Hint:** $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$. Now set $a=e$ and ...

Comment: Thanks. Incredibly sad that I did not think to use that.

Answer (score 0):

$f(t) = e^{-0.001t}\cdot{e^{-0.005t}}\\
f(t) = e^{-0.001t+(-0.005t)}\\
f(t) = e^{-0.006t} \\
y = e^{-0.006t} \\
inverse:t = e^{-0.006y}\\
-0.006y = ln(t) \\
y = -\frac{1}{0.006}\ln(t)\\
y = -166.667\ln(t)$

EDIT: Note that $ln{a^{b}} = b\ln{a}$ and $\ln{e} = 1$